# Ruida contorller(CNC) Data file with .bs extension

Tags: file, controller, data-files, cnc

I have an CNC with Ruida Controller(RDC6332G-BS) that seem to work only with data files that have a .bs file extension, i can't fount out any application that can open this data file.
i tried with XnView  but same thing.
When i try to copy for exemple an RD file with .rd extension(via usb disk) to that CNC laser cuter, it not apear in the menu of UDisk, i copy the default file existed in the memory of the CNC to Udisk, and move out to the PC, i found the extension of that file is .bs, but i can't found any application (RDWork or XnView or Corel) that can open this file!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure it is actually a ruida-compatible file you could try to render it using [rdint](https://github.com/kallaballa/rdint) which is an interpreter and debugger for ruida files.

(I am the author of rdint)